# Kubernetes Ingress - cannot access

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

I'm new to Ingress in Kubernetes. I installed Ingress NGINX controller in my AKS cluster. My application runs in a pod (Port 80) in testns (Namespace). I created a service for it in the same namespace. Now I want to access my application from outside. So I created an Ingress yaml for it.

**service.yaml**

```
 kubectl get svc -A | grep my-svc
    testns    my-svc                         ClusterIP      10.0.116.192   <none>          80/TCP                             93m
```

**ingress**

```
Name:             example-ingress
Namespace:        testns
Address:
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  *
              /apple   my-svc:80 (10.244.1.33:80)
Annotations:  ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
Events:       <none>
```

**ingress.yaml**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
        - path: /apple
          backend:
            serviceName: my-svc
            servicePort: 80
```

When I access using the **<IP_ADDRESS_OF_THE_INGRESS>/apple**, it gives an 404 error. I want to know why the application can't be accessed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the ingress class into YAML config `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"`

as annotation

```
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
```

Example

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
        - path: /apple
          backend:
            serviceName: my-svc
            servicePort: 80
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Can you explain me what does this mean? "kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx" ?

Comment: And now if I curl it gives 308 permanent redirect response

Comment: class basiclly use for pointing the ingress to ingress controller, so if you are running the multiple ingress inside single cluster you have to use the class name so different ingress can connect to their respective controoler.